# Javascript replace coordinate [1.111111,2.22222]

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sed, gps, coordinate

I had been searching for so long without success...

I would like in JavaScript make my `[1.111111,2.222222]` coordinates into:

- lat = 1.111111
- lng = 2.222222

Like this I will be able to treat them. Sorry for this newbie question, hope will help future beginners as me :)

Thanks !

Comment: What's this got to do with `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking to take an array of numbers into their separate variables?

For instance:

```
var array = [1.111111 , 2.222222];
var lat = array[0]; //lat is now equal to 1.111111
var lng = array[1]; //lng is now equal to 2.222222`
```

If not, can you please give a little more detail?